# android: Desugaring of ZonedDateTime results in TimeOffset being null

Tags: android, java-time, android-r8, jdk-desugaring, threetenabp

I'm trying to migrate from [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to [java.time with desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring). On debug builds this works perfectly, but on release builds (`minifyEnabled = true`) I get a weird error on runtime.

After a ZonedDateTime is serialized (passing a Bundle in an Intent), the ZonedDateTime is lacking the TimeOffset:

before:  `2022-06-07T02:00+02:00`

after: `2022-06-07T02:00null`

I'm using gradle version 7.2.1 (AGP 7.3.3) in combination with the basic backup from the android docs listed above. (changing it to java 11 does not fix the problem)

```
android {
  ...

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs (java.time)
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  ...
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5"
}
```

Do I miss any configuration (e.g. in proguard-rules)? How can I fix this issue?

UPDATE 1: 09.06.2022
Here is a minimal reproducable example of the problem. Keep in mind that this only happens with `minifyEnabled = true`

```
val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-06-07T02:00:00.000+02:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSVV"))
// zonedDateTime.toString() == "2022-06-07T02:00+02:00"


val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putSerializable("date", zonedDateTime)
    
bundle.getSerializable("date") // .toString() == "2022-06-07T02:00null"
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mre]? Which code creates the `ZonedDateTime` in the first place?

Comment: Opened https://issuetracker.google.com/235932415 on the R8 issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general issue was that the desugar_jdk_libs ["did not support Serialization with the default java serializer in desugared library besides collections"](https://issuetracker.google.com/235932415).

This issue is resolved in version 1.1.6 of the library:

```
coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.6"
```

Now everything wokrs as expected when minify is enabled!